# Passing variables to php page acting as state in Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router

This is my current setup:

In an Angular driven environment, I have several states that are mapped to a PHP page. Those PHP pages depent on specific data variables, which I would normally (outside of Angular) provide as GET parameters.

Now, I would like to be able to change to such a PHP page by actually loading it inside my Angular environment by switching states (which I already can because I mapped those PHP pages to Angular states) and immediately send some variables along with the state change (like employeeID). Now I know how to send along stateParams, but I see no way of how to instantly have hem 'picked up' and read by the PHP page that is being called. I tried everything, including packing them as GET variables inside the state request URL, but nothing seems to work.

I would rather not like to use AJAX and a $http.post or $http.get request once my PHP has already been loaded, because this in my opinion would only cost valueble loading time - I would rather want the variables to somehow be fed to PHP immediately on the page load, as would be the case with GET variables, so PHP can immediately 'generate' and serve the correct page containing the correct data (based on those variables).

Hope this can be done somehow and somebody knows how to do it.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.

This helped me solve this issue:

[Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28074306/553258)

Essentially, I just needed to update my template function for the state I wanted the variables to be forwarded to and used by:

```
templateUrl: function(attrs){ 
     return basepath('../../index.php?employeeID=') + attrs.employeeID+ '&contactID=' + attrs.contactID;
},
```